# Android Studio - Android Monitor: Much too large indent when displaying exceptions

Tags: android, layout, monitor

The indent used by the Android Monitor (I assume) to display exceptions is approximately "half the screen width", while "one tab" would be sufficient. The result is that horisontal scrolling becomes mandatory and this is just annoying and tedious in use.

Is there a way to drastically reduce this indent?

[image]

Comment: Can't believe there are not more people disturbed by this! It's so annoying, especially when working on a "smaller" screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by modifying the log headers. According to `Android Studio`'s documentation you can reduce the log header by the following:

> 1. Select Use Soft Wraps Use Soft Wraps icon to see the entire message
>    and prevent it from running off of the right edge.
> 2. Click Configure Logcat Header Configure Logcat header icon to specify elements of the
>    messages that you want to show or hide, and then click OK.

For more information please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is a bit helpful, but it does not remove the colossal indent.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea how to accomplish that